# How to convert HTML string to HTMLDivElement Object in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

HTML code is returning from api function as a string format. 
**var div = infoWindow.getContent();** the div variable contains the following code.

```
<div class="mt">
    <div class="fl">
        <a id="detailsLink" class="jsDetailsLink" href="/profile/369/john">More profile information</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

. 
 I want to convert to **[object HTMLDivElement]** in `jQuery`. If it is converted into object `HTMLDivElement`, I can easily change the a href value through **JS code**.
 How to convert that?

Answer (score 5):

Consider you have the following string:

```
var string = '<div class="mt"><div class="fl"><a id="detailsLink" class="jsDetailsLink" href="/profile/369/john">More profile information</a></div></div>';
```

You can pass it to `$` function, and jQuery power will be in your hands:

```
var $elem = $(string);
```

Now you can get the link within it:

```
$elem.find('a').attr('href', 'http://www.google.com/');
```

And append it to some element:

```
$elem.appendTo('body');
```

---

- `[!]` You can check it at this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/sGfwy/).

Answer (score 0):

Try  with **.html** like

```
$(".mt").html();
```

and if you want to change the href value you can try like

```
$(".jsDetailsLink").attr("href","my_new_href");
```

you need some practise and see this [**JQUERY**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a dummy object and append your string to that object after that replace HREF value by jQuery.

```
var str = '<div class="mt"><div class="fl"><a id="detailsLink" class="jsDetailsLink" href="/profile/369/john">More profile information</a></div></div>';
var dummy = $('<div />');
dummy.html(str);
dummy.find('#detailsLink').attr('href', 'http://google.com'); 
alert(dummy.html());
    $('#data').text(dummy.html());
```