# HTML string to convert in HTMLdivelement object, to load in fbox

Tags: jquery

HTML code is returning from api function as a string format. 
**var div = infoWindow.getContent();** the div variable contains the following code.

```
<div class="mt">
    <div class="fl">
        <a id="detailsLink" class="jsDetailsLink" href="/profile/369/john">More profile information</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

. 
 I want to convert to **[object HTMLDivElement]** in `jQuery`. If it is converted into object `HTMLDivElement`, I can easily change the a href value through **JS code**.
 How to convert that? 
 This is my following JS code to change the a href value and open in facebox 
**var link = div.down('a.jsDetailsLink'); 

link.href = '/ajax/?action=hotelInfoFull&id=' + id; 

new Facebox(link);**

Comment: See my ans for your previous qustion,you can get ans http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16684240/how-to-convert-html-string-to-htmldivelement-object-in-jquery

Comment: Hey man same question , i just checked your previous question which is already answered ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16684240/how-to-convert-html-string-to-htmldivelement-object-in-jquery

Comment: But i want to use the above js code to load the new ahref value for open in the facebox. with the link variable itself. please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var string = '<div class="mt"><div class="fl"><a id="detailsLink" class="jsDetailsLink" href="/profile/369/john">More profile information</a></div></div>';

var $x = $(string);
$x.find('a.jsDetailsLink').attr('href', '/ajax/?action=hotelInfoFull&id=' + id;)
new Facebox($x.get(0));
```